# как определить попал ли div при перемещении в другой

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-n-drop

определить попал ли div при перемещении в другой

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>блок один</p>
</div>
<div id='res'>
  <p>блок два</p>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это вопрос про jquery ui или в целом про логику? Если в целом, то очевидно же, что сравниваются координаты верха,низа, правой и левой стороны каждого из фигур и на основе этого делается предположение

Comment: напишите примерно как будет

Comment: Если леваяСторонаБелогоПрямоугольника по координате X больше чем леваяСторонаЗеленогоПрямоугольника по координате X  **И**  праваяСторонаБелогоПрямоугольника по координате X меньше чем праваяСторонаЗеленогоПрямоугольника по координате X  **И** верхБелогоПрямоугольника по координате Y больше чем верхЗеленогоПрямоугольника по координате Y  **И**  низБелогоПрямоугольника по координате Y меньше чем низЗеленогоПрямоугольника по координате Y, то значит белый внутри...... это, в принципе, видно из рисунка

Answer (score 2):

Способов много, зависит от Вашей реализации.
Если через `HTML5` (`draggable`), то использовать событие `dragover`, которое активируется при помещении перетаскиваемого объекта в зону прослушиваемого элемента.
Правда [событие] возникает весьма часто, решается регулированием функции.

```js
let res = document.querySelector('#res');

function _dragOver(e){ // Много, много раз
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  console.info('Я над зоной посадки!');
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
}

res.addEventListener("dragover", _dragOver, false);
```

```css
#draggable{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#res{
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable" draggable='true' class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>блок один</p>
</div>
<div id='res'>
  <p>блок два</p>
</div>
```

Если по старинке, через `onmousedown`/`onmousemove`/`onmouseup`, то в событии `onmousemove` берёте координаты курсора (`Event.pageX`/`Event.pageY`) и смотрите есть ли по этим координатам зона посадки (`Document.elementFromPoint`, `Element.closest`).

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag

`    
          
           This div is draggable

```
<style>
  #draggable {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
  }

  .dropzone {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    background: blueviolet;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
</style>

<script>
  var dragged;

  /* events fired on the draggable target */
  document.addEventListener("drag", function( event ) {

  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragstart", function( event ) {
      // store a ref. on the dragged elem
      dragged = event.target;
      // make it half transparent
      event.target.style.opacity = .5;
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragend", function( event ) {
      // reset the transparency
      event.target.style.opacity = "";
  }, false);

  /* events fired on the drop targets */
  document.addEventListener("dragover", function( event ) {
      // prevent default to allow drop
      event.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragenter", function( event ) {
      // highlight potential drop target when the draggable element enters it
      if ( event.target.className == "dropzone" ) {
          event.target.style.background = "purple";
      }

  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragleave", function( event ) {
      // reset background of potential drop target when the draggable element leaves it
      if ( event.target.className == "dropzone" ) {
          event.target.style.background = "";
      }

  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("drop", function( event ) {
      // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
      event.preventDefault();
      // move dragged elem to the selected drop target
      if ( event.target.className == "dropzone" ) {
          event.target.style.background = "";
          dragged.parentNode.removeChild( dragged );
          event.target.appendChild( dragged );
      }

  }, false);`
</script>
```

Comment: Вот только это не совсем то, что вы описали в вопросе)) ибо тут событие срабатывает не когда один объект полностью будет внутри другого, а при некотором проценте захода... )) "overlap" так сказать